# Facebook Canvas page Error "The server refused the connection." node.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-canvas

I am trying to make Facebook Canvas app using node.js, currently hosted on my laptop (localhost). I am on a windows 7 OS and do not have a firewall. I'm trying to get [nodejs-fb-sample-app](https://github.com/daaku/nodejs-fb-sample-app) running.

I set the environment variables and created an app in Facebook, with the following:

- Canvas URL: `http://localhost:3000/`
- Secure Canvas URL: `https://localhost:3000/`

When visiting `https://apps.facebook.com/cu-fb-app-test/` I get the error `SSL protocol error` on the facebook canvas page.  This question may be specific to the code from github but why is this error caused?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have secure browsing enable in Fb, but your node server doesn't support https...